# In lightning console whenever I click any button in the Quote (CPQ) page it open in a new tab (Sub Tab ?). I don't want this

Tags: cpq, lightning-console

In lightning console whenever I click any button on the Quote (CPQ) object record page it open in a new tab (Sub Tab ?). Like when it Edit Lines the Quote line editor open in a new tab(sub tab?). I don't want this to happen. I want it to open in same page. This behaviour is happening in lightning console view only. Is there some general setting for this ? Sorry I don't know much about lightning console.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to set the navigation rules in Lightning App settings. [image: app-setup]